# Encrypt auto generated sql connection string by Entity framework in WebService project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-services, wcf

I have a web service project which has connection with Database, so that I have .edmx file with auto generated sql connection string in web.config file. Now my question is, how to encrypt this auto generated sql connection string in web.config file, which is generated by Entity framework ?

I already came across aspnet_regiis.exe and programmatic encryption methodologies.

So please help me to resolve this...